# how to parse string to int in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want  int from string in javascript how i can get them from

test1 , stsfdf233,  fdfk323,

are anyone show me the method to get the integer from this string.

it is a rule that int is always in the back of the string.

how i can get the int who was at last in my string

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
var s = 'abc123';
var number = s.match(/\d+$/);
number = parseInt(number, 10);
```

The first step is a simple regular expression - `\d+$` will match the digits near the end.
On the next step, we use `parseInt` on the *string* we've matched before, to get a proper number.

Comment: @Chinmayee: "it is a rule that int is always in the back of the string"

Comment: That's *really* sloppy, though, treating the array as though it were a string and counting on `Array#toString` (perhaps you meant `parseInt(number[0], 10)`). Also assumes there will be a match (`number` can come back `null` if there isn't.)

Comment: @elusive - it does, I even checked before posting (I'm quick): http://jsbin.com/oconi5 . Notice I don't need a capturing group.

Comment: @elusive: Oh, it works. It works because the call to `parseInt` coerces the array into a string, and **if** the array has only one entry, you'll get that entry. It's just very sloppy and prone to failure.

Comment: @Kobi: Take a look at T.J. Crowder's comment. @T.J. Crowder: Thats right. I highly discourage from using it like that. It is not guranteed that this will work everywhere.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - I'm getting a `Nan` in case there wasn't a match. Doesn't seem like a big deal in a language like JavaScript, though I suppose a short validation and `number[0]` might be prettier.

Comment: @elusive: It works because the first step of `parseInt` is to call `ToString` on the input, in this case an array, and then it is a string. See section 15.1.2.2 in ECMA-262 specification.

Comment: @Kobi - That may be worse since `.match()` returns `null` if there's no match, you'd be doing `null[0]`, which would be invalid. EDIT: I missed the part where you wrote "short validation".

Comment: I would also note that in JavaScript `1 == [1]` is `true`, and even `[[[[2]]]] == 2` - JavaScript also treats a single-element array as the element. I guess JavaScript is a sloppy language `:)`

Comment: @Kobi: *"I guess JavaScript is a sloppy language"* I disagree. There's a lot of sloppy JavaScript *code* out there, but the language isn't sloppy.

Comment: Given the reference @some made to the spec, I'm not certain this would be a bad (or sloppy) solution (unless there's some known flaw in a relevant js implementation).

Comment: @patrick: It makes it really, really fragile, and sets a snare to trip up code maintainers. There are lots of things one *can* do that one *shouldn't* do, particularly in such a powerful and flexible language as JavaScript. But sure, if you do it, comment it clearly ("// Relies on implicit `toString`, will get NaN if `number` is `null`.").

Comment: @T.J. By the same token, then it would seem that javascript should return NaN when passed an Array instead of doing a `toString` on your behalf. Anyway, I can see your point that `NaN` may not be anticipated as readily as `undefined`. Perhaps a concise solution would be `number = parseInt(number, 10) || undefined;`. EDIT: Although the `if()` in your answer does eliminate an unnecessary `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp) to extract the numbers in the string via [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), and convert each of them to a number via [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var str, matches, index, num;

str = "test123and456";
matches = str.match(/\d+/g);
for (index = 0; index < matches.length; ++index) {
    num = parseInt(matches[index], 10);
    display("Digit series #" + index + " converts to " + num);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ayoyo4)

**If** the numbers really occur only at the ends of the strings or you just want to convert the *first* set of digits you find, you can simplify a bit:

```
var str, matches, num;

str = "test123";
matches = str.match(/\d+/);
if (matches) {
    num = parseInt(matches[0], 10);
    display("Found match, converts to: " + num);
}
else {
    display("No digits found");
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ayoyo4/2)

If you want to *ignore* digits that aren't at the end, add `$` to the end of the regex:

```
matches = str.match(/\d+$/);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ayoyo4/3)

Comment: That's `/\d+$/`. Cool `if`, by the way `:)`

Comment: @Kobi: **Thanks** for catching the `$` thing, I caught it in the example but hadn't realized I'd typed it in the text (I normally *copy* from the example to the text, not the other way around).

Comment: +1 An `if(matches)` I'm certain will be a faster test than relying on `parseInt()` to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "stsfdf233";
var num = parseInt(str.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
```

Comment: Note : this solution works even if numbers are not at the end of string (also for string like ab12c34)

Comment: @fcalderan: Yeah, but almost certainly *not the way it's supposed to*. (Your "ab12c34" example will return the number 1,234. Desired result? I doubt it.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var match = "stsfdf233".match(/\d+$/);
var result = 0; // default value
if(match != null) {
    result = parseInt(match[0], 10); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative, this time without any replace or Regular Expression, just one simple loop:

```
function ExtractInteger(sValue)
{
    var sDigits = "";
    for (var i = sValue.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var c = sValue.charAt(i);
        if (c < "0" || c > "9")
            break;
        sDigits = c + sDigits;
    }
    return (sDigits.length > 0) ? parseInt(sDigits, 10) : NaN;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var s = "stsfdf233";
var n = ExtractInteger(s);
alert(n);
```

Comment: One small comment - you want to call `parseInt(sDigits, 10)`, try `abc012`, and then `abc09`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
var str = 'abc123';
var number = str.match(/\d/g).join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my extension to String class :

```
String.prototype.toInt=function(){
    return parseInt(this.replace(/\D/g, ''),10);
}
```

Then  :

```
"ddfdsf121iu".toInt();
```

Will return an integer : `121`

Answer (score 0):

First positive or negative number:

```
"foo-22bar11".match(/-?\d+/); // -22
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: this is wrong as it doesn't answer but shouldn't be deleted. It has value. It finds the first

Comment: OP did not ask for all occurences, neither did i want that. And none of the given answers take into account negative numbers and that is what i needed so i figured this out.

Answer (score -2):

```
javascript:alert('stsfdf233'.match(/\d+$/)[0])
```

`Global.parseInt` with `radix` is overkill here, regexp extracted decimal digits already and rigth trimmed string