# Score field in html text acts as string when trying to = -= values

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a score board, and its adding on numbers weirdly:

My html:

```
<div id="game-info">
   Top score: <p id="top-score">0</p><br>
    Current score: <p id="current">0</p><br>
    Games played: <p id="played-games">0</p>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
var score = document.getElementById("current");
if(blabla scored points){
     score.innerHTML += 100;
}
if(blabla scored -points){
    score.innerHTML -= 10;
}
```

The minus points work fine-ish, at least it adds up negatively, but the positive score will add itself to the end on the current score, like so:

```
Current score: <p id="current">0100</p><br>
```

or

```
Current score: <p id="current">-20100</p><br>
```

Does this have anything to do with that its a string and not an int? Im confused why the negative score works and the positive doesnt when its the same markup..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concatenating a string ... you need to convert the current score to a number first - try something like this :

```
var score = document.getElementById("current");
if(blabla scored points){
     // parse current score as integer and then add 100
     score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML,10) + 100;
}
if(blabla scored -points){
    // parse current score as integer and then subtract 10
    score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML,10) - 10;
}
```

[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) parses a string to an integer

Extra note: when using `parseInt()` and using a radix

> An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. **Always specify this parameter** to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.

Comment: What does the 10 do in (score.innerHTML,10)? Just out of curiosity :) its not obvious to me..

Comment: I have included a link to the docs for `parseInt` - MDN is a great place to read the docs for JavaScript

Comment: Thanks I checked it out but didnt exactly understand. I think MDN isnt noob-friendly enough for me (might have to do with english not being my first language), but google is my friend! :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that subtracting a score works better than adding a score is that the `+` operator is overloaded for strings (such as `innerHTML`) to mean string concatenation, while the `-` operator is not overloaded with any special meaning for strings.

Thus, `score.innerHTML += 100` will choose the overload of the `+` operator that applies to strings and implicitly convert 100 to a string and append '100' to the current score string value.

But, `score.innerHTML -= 10` will choose the meaning of the `-` operator that applies to numeric values, and thus it is forced to attempt to cast the innerHTML value to a numeric value (which it can do successfully) and subtract 10 from that value, and then convert the result back to a string when assigning the result to `score.innerHTML`. In fact, you could even put quotes around the 10 in the subtraction expression and it would still work, it would just attempt to convert that back to a number as well. If score.innerHTML happened to be a string that could not be converted to a number, like "abc", then the string would be converted to `NaN`, and the subtraction would result in NaN, which would be converted to the string "NaN" when being assigned to the innerHTML value.

As other answers to this question have described, using `parseInt` is a good way to force both operands of the `+=` operator to be numeric, thus ensuring that addition instead of string concatenation is performed.

Comment: Great explanation! Apparently because javascript is retarded and gets overloaded by + it works differently than - xD weird. I wonder what the result would be if you mixed in * and /.

Comment: Using the * and / operators would have the same result as the subtraction expression, because there are no overloads of these operators for string values.

Comment: Note that the + operator is overloaded in many languages, including C, Java, etc. The difference is that Javascript uses dynamic/weak typing, whereas the latter languages are statically/strongly typed. For Javascript this means that types are inferred from values at run-time, not from variables at compile time. Thus, implicit conversions like this are an explicit part of the design. Though it can cause some unexpected behavior as discussed here, it makes common tasks such as working with the DOM much easier.

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is a string.  You can use `parseInt` to convert it to an integer before incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because the value of "current" is actually a string so += will just add what it thinks are two string together.

You need to parse the value before you can do any maths with it, see this question for an example that includes checking if it is a number before using parseInt():

[how to parse string to int in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194092/how-to-parse-string-to-int-in-javascript)