# How to test type of input into prompt for conditional statement - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, types, prompt

If i want write an if statement where on the web page a prompt for your username pops up and i want it to be a string only how do i do this. For example if you type in a string it would say "username accepted" but if you type in a number it would say "username denied". The code I have so far says Username Accepted everytime.

```
let webUser = prompt("Please create a username", "typehere");

if (webUser != null) {
  document.getElementById("root").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + webUser + "! How are you today?";
}

if (typeof webUser == 'string' || webUser instanceof String) {
  alert('Username Accepted')
} else {
  alert('Username Denied')
}
```

Comment: Prompt always returns a string. It will never return a number or null.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement without `RegEx`:

```js
let webUser = prompt("Please create a username", "typehere");

if (webUser != null) {
 document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "Hello " + webUser + "! How are you today?";
}

if (isNaN(+webUser)) {  
 alert('Username Accepted');
}
else {
 alert('Username Denied') ; 
}
```

```html
<div id="root">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of value you get from a `prompt` will *always* be a string, even if it has numbers in it. If you want to check to see if a string consists of only numbers, you can use a regular expression:

```
const webUser = prompt("Please create a username", "typehere");
if (/^\d+$/.test(webUser.trim())) console.log('invalid');
else console.log('valid');
```

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` always returns a string data type. What you are trying to determine is whether that string is parseable as an integer. You can see some examples of how to do so here:
[how to parse string to int in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194092/how-to-parse-string-to-int-in-javascript#4194114)

Comment: Thanks I’ll check it out